# Task T.IsCancelled = false; How can I make this true?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, desktop-application, cancellationtokensource

I have this asynchronous method :

```
private static async Task Initializ( ) { /*Do Stuff Here*/ }
```

I want to be able to monitor the task that results from calling this function :

```
Task T = Class.Initialize( );
if (T.IsCancelled){ /*Do Stuff Here*/ }
```

I have in place a `CancellationTokenSource`.

How can I make `T` (or the function `Initialize`) utilize that sources token such that if it is cancelled, `T.IsCancelled` will be true?

### EDIT

I do not know for certain but I think the answer to my question lies within using a `TaskCompletionSource` object. The answer given by Mike has lead me to this conclusion...

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A Task will complete in the TaskStatus.Canceled state under any of
>   the following conditions:
>
> - Its CancellationToken was marked for cancellation before the task
>     started executing,
> - The task acknowledged the cancellation request on its already signaled
>     CancellationToken by throwing an OperationCanceledException that bears
>     the same CancellationToken.
> - The task acknowledged the cancellation request on its already signaled
>     CancellationToken by calling the ThrowIfCancellationRequested method
>     on the CancellationToken.

Comment: A `CancellationToken` isn't required for a task to be marked as canceled but this is one documented way to achieve that.

Comment: @Lukazoid actually, if you throw a `OperationCanceledException` and that exception was not linked to the task it will not show the task as canceled. Async tasks are a special case I believe, but if you where doing the same operation in a `Task.Run(SomeFunction, myToken)` the token is required to be linked to the exception to get in to the canceled state.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain But my point still stands, a `CancellationToken` isn't required, there are other alternatives.

Comment: @Lukazoid I was just trying to clarify, it is not required *for the OP's case* but it could be required for other cases.

Comment: This answer makes sense to me; however I am not calling `task.run(() => {/*Do Stuff*/}, /*CancellationToken*/);`. This `async` method is too complex for that (and relies on libraries that are already in place which make use of `async` methods (before I began to explore task cancellation).

I just need to know if it is possible for me to see that the `Task T` resultant from calling the `Initialize` function would have it's `IsCancelled` property show `true` if a furnished `CancellationToken` were to have it's `Cancel( )` method called.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

Use this method:

```
async Task<Task> UntilCompletionOrCancellation(Task asyncOp, CancellationToken ct)
{
   var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(); 

   using(ct.Register(() => tcs.TrySetResult(true)))
       await Task.WhenAny(asyncOp, tcs.Task); 

   return asyncOp;
}
```

Consuming task:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

await UntilCompletionOrCancellation(Class.Initialize, cts.Token);

if (!Class.Initialize.IsCompleted)
{
    /*Do Stuff Here*/ 
}
```

Another approach is to remove async from Initialize

```
 private static Task Initialize()
 {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();

    //use TrySetResult or TrySetCancelled 

    return tcs.Task;
 }
```

You can await this task and check whether is canceled or completed.

Comment: That won't work - I'm already doing something like that, but I need to monitor the `Task` that comes from calling `Class.Initialize` to watch it. This answer does not address my question.

Comment: I will try this in a simple program and see what happens.

Comment: That doesn't work either - An `async Task` function cannot return a value; trying to `return asyncOp` fails.

Comment: @Will sorry forgot return type

Comment: This still isn't exactly right but I think it does lead me to the correct answer - I believe that I need to just use a `TaskCompletionSource` object and set it's property through `TrySetCancelled` appropriately...

Comment: @Will added some idea using TaskCompletionSource

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to just throw an `OperationCanceledException` from your asynchronous method.

The following writes `true` to the console:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DoSomethingAsync().IsCanceled);
}

private static async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{    
    throw new OperationCanceledException();
}
```

A nicer way to support cancellation is to have your asynchronous method take a `CancellationToken` as a parameter, it may then use this token to check for cancellation, e.g:

```
public static async Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{    
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the method and let the exception bubble up.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task T = Class.Initialize(cts.Token);
if (T.IsCancelled){ /*Do Stuff Here*/ }

private static async Task Initializ(CancellationToken token ) 
{
  /*Do Stuff Here*/ 
  token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  /*Do More Stuff Here*/ 
}
```